# Roll over / Hovering tabs not displaying correctly in IE8

Tags: php, jquery

Check this page. On either firefox, chrome, or IE9 / 10 the tabs on the header display uniform and hover correctly. However on IE8 The tabs step down and disappear off of the header. Anyone familiar with this problem?

http://www.seanprovost.com/frah_dev/newclients.php

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$("#nav1").animate({
    marginTop: "50px"
}, 'slow');
$("#nav2").animate({
    marginTop: "50px"
}, 'slow');
$("#nav3").animate({
    marginTop: "50px"
}, 'slow');
$("#nav4").animate({
    marginTop: "50px"
}, 'slow');
$("#nav5").animate({
    marginTop: "50px"
}, 'slow');

//Animal Care Animation
$("#link_ac").hover( function() {
    $("#nav1").animate({ marginTop: "0px" }, 'slow');
}, function() {
    $("#nav1").animate({ marginTop: "50px" }, 'slow');
});
//Animal Care Rollover
$("#link_ac").hover( function() {
    $("#nav1").css({"background-image" : "url('i/nav_ac_o.png')" });
}, function() {
    $("#nav1").css({"background-image" : "url('i/nav_ac.png')" });
});
//Our Team Animation
$("#link_ot").hover( function() {
    $("#nav2").animate({ marginTop: "0px" }, 'slow');
}, function() {
    $("#nav2").animate({ marginTop: "50px" }, 'slow');
});
//Our Team Rollover
$("#link_ot").hover( function() {
    $("#nav2").css({"background-image" : "url('i/nav_ot_o.png')" });
}, function() {
    $("#nav2").css({"background-image" : "url('i/nav_ot.png')" });
});
//Boarding Animation
$("#link_b").hover( function() {
    $("#nav3").animate({ marginTop: "0px" }, 'slow');
}, function() {
    $("#nav3").animate({ marginTop: "50px" }, 'slow');
});
//Boarding Rollover
$("#link_b").hover( function() {
    $("#nav3").css({"background-image" : "url('i/nav_b_o.png')" });
}, function() {
    $("#nav3").css({"background-image" : "url('i/nav_b.png')" });
});
//New Clients Animation
$("#link_nc").hover( function() {
    $("#nav4").animate({ marginTop: "0px" }, 'slow');
}, function() {
    $("#nav4").animate({ marginTop: "50px" }, 'slow');
});
//New Clients Rollover
$("#link_nc").hover( function() {
    $("#nav4").css({"background-image" : "url('i/nav_nc_o.png')" });
}, function() {
    $("#nav4").css({"background-image" : "url('i/nav_nc.png')" });
});
//Grooming Animation
$("#link_g").hover( function() {
    $("#nav5").animate({ marginTop: "0px" }, 'slow');
}, function() {
    $("#nav5").animate({ marginTop: "50px" }, 'slow');
});
//Grooming Rollover
$("#link_g").hover( function() {
    $("#nav5").css({"background-image" : "url('i/nav_g_o.png')" });
}, function() {
    $("#nav5").css({"background-image" : "url('i/nav_g.png')" });
});
```

Comment: yes, use `stop()` before `animate()` method.

Comment: start with valid html: http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.seanprovost.com%2Ffrah_dev%2Fnewclients.php

Comment: Thank you undefined. Could you give me an example of what you mean? Description edited to include animation code. Post as an answer please so I can mark as an answer and add to your rep :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css for the nav elements needs some work. Use a console to inspect the `LI` and  `<a>` tags etc will see that IE is seeing the positioning of them differently due to lack of css structure on the main elements and floats within those elements.

Also validator is showing broken tags in page. Beef up the css on nav, fix broken tags and you should be better off cross browser

EDIT: disable javascript and will see that jQuery is not the culprit

Answer (score 0):

instead of using two `hover` handlers you can combine them, and try `stop()` method:

```
   $("#link_ac").hover( function() {
        $("#nav1").stop().animate({ marginTop: "0px" }, 'slow');
        $("#nav1").css({"background-image" : "url('i/nav_ac_o.png')" });
    }, function() {
        $("#nav1").stop().animate({ marginTop: "50px" }, 'slow');
        $("#nav1").css({"background-image" : "url('i/nav_ac.png')" });
    });
```

Comment: Seems to still have the same issue. instead of all tabs being inline across the top they seem to step down like a set of stairs :/ Only in IE8 or earlier though. They display fine on any other browser

Comment: @user1411823 sorry i'm on Macintosh and don't have access to IE8.